# After running yarn eject on create-react-app throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('path', 'string', path);

Tags: reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg

After running `yarn eject` on `create-react-app` when I try to run `yarn start` the terminal shows error something like this:

```
$ node scripts/start.js
path.js:39
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('path', 'string', path);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. R
eceived type undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:39:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:168:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\aditya-portfolio\config\webpack.config.d
ev.js:193:39)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\aditya-portfolio\scripts\start.js:31:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this com
mand.
```

I was trying to config SCSS in webpack config file but after doing the config when I try to run `yarn start` it always fails with the above error. How can I fix this?

Comment: how did you add scss?

Comment: @PlayMa256 i changed css to scss in wepack.config.dev file

Comment: the modification that you have done. Otherwise i can't say what is wrong.

Comment: Have you found out any solution for this ?

Comment: @Zakawat I run `yarn install ` again and this fixed my problem.

Comment: @adityakumar this issue was a bug in the latest version of ReactNative. for more info and how to FIX it, please visit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24107

Comment: @Zakawat this issue is closed anyway. although i never tried this in react native. I got this from reactjs.